# Code structure with Asynctask Android

Tags: java, android, coding-style, android-asynctask

I guess I am just producing "Spaghetti-Code". Perhabs some experts can help me write a better code for my solution. Following Pseudocodes will show my problem:

I have some procedures that runs long. This procedures will show a progressbar. I use Asynctasks to achieve this. This all works fine, but my code is not maintainable anymore :

My wish to leave it simple code without nesting code  :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
LongrunningTask1();
dosomething1();
LongrunningTask2();
dosomething2();
LongrunningTask3();
dosomething3();
LongrunningTask4();
dosomething4(); 
}
```

My Code with Asynctasks :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    new LongrunningTask1().execute("Task1");

}
class LongrunningTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, boolean> {
        private Exception exception;
        protected RSSFeed doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                Do;
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        updateprogressbar();
    }

        protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {
        dosomething1();
        new LongrunningTask2().execute("Task2");
        }
     }
class LongrunningTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, boolean> {
    similar to LongrunningTask1

        protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {
        dosomething2();
        new LongrunningTask3().execute("Task3");
        }

}
class LongrunningTask3 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, boolean> {
    similar to LongrunningTask2

        protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {
        dosomething3();
        new LongrunningTask4().execute("Task4");
        }
}
class LongrunningTask4 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, boolean> {
    similar to LongrunningTask3

        protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {
        dosomething4();
        }
}
```

I would like to avoid any nesting calls. Can anyone help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to execute them all in separate threads? You could do them all in a single AsyncTask.

Maybe you could take a took at the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)? I used it to solve something similar.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. Of course it would be easier to execute all the stuff in one thread, but no I need the have threads sequentially. ThreadPoolExecutor is good to know for other situations. But in my case i really like to have a simple solution, if there is one.